# Selecting div which was created by Jquery .load

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am having an issue whilst trying to write content to a div which was created by jQuery .load() has been called.

I understand that this can be achieved by binding an element inside of the `.on("click","el", func(){})` - but the content which needs to be written to the div via .html() is fired by another function which checks the # in the url, not an event. As shown below:

```
function check_loaded_moduels()
{
    var current_loc = window.location.hash;

    if (current_loc == "#GamesLibrary")
    {
        load_user_games();
    }
}

function load_user_games()
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "load_user_games.php",
        dataType: "html"
    })
   .done(function(user_games)
   {
       $('.main_section').on("change", "#user_games", function()
       {
           $(".right_games_holder").html(user_games);
       })
   });
}
```

The Div I am targeting is not initially loaded into the DOM, which explains why jQuery cannot find it, although, I use another div which is directly bound with 
.on() which works as expected. However, this one does not.

I have tried using

```
$(document).on("change",".right_games_holder", function()
{
   $(".right_games_holder").html(user_games);
});
```

but to no avail. I can't seem to find any alternative for this issue without binding an event to the element with .on(), although, as explained, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.main_section').on("change", "#user_games", function(){
    $(this).find(".right_games_holder").html(user_games);
})
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't work as no fields are changing. Also tested, no result.